# Why am I constantly receiving the same image from Unsplash API despite following their documentation?

Tags: api, next.js

I cannot get a random image from Unsplash, instead I keep getting the same image over and over again

According to their docs the address I am using should use the API, and display a random image every refresh, I used the API link directly on the navigator's search bar and I can confirm it sends the JSON, yet on my app it doesn't asks Unsplash API for any new image

````
import Image from "next/image";
import { UnsplashImage } from "@/models/unsplash-image";
import Link from "next/link";


export default async function Page(){
    const response = await fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=" + process.env.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY)
    const image: UnsplashImage = await response.json();

    const width = Math.min(500, image.width); 
    const height = (width / image.width) + image.height;


return(
    <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-cente "> 
    <Image
        src={image.urls.raw}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        alt={image.description}
        className="rounded shadow mw-100 h-100"
    
    />
        by <Link href={"/users/" + image.user.username}> {image.user.username} </Link>

    </div>

)


}```


I used `    const response = await fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=" + process.env.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY)
`
Yet I still keep getting the same image, the API uses don't reflect any use though 
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN3fl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN3fl.png)
````

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
const [img, setImg] = useState(null)

    useEffect(()=>{
         const getImage = async ()=> {
            const response = await fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=" + process.env.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY)
            const image: UnsplashImage = await response.json();
            setImg(image) 
        }
        getImage()
    },[])

    const width = Math.min(500, img.width); 
    const height = (width / img.width) + img.height;

.............

    <Image
    src={img.urls.raw} // set the random image
    width={width}
    height={height}
    alt={img.description}
    className="rounded shadow mw-100 h-100"

/>
```

The above might not be the exact solution, but I think you should explore using the useEffect hook to asynchronously fetch the data and render in the UI.